# ViennaRNA package's Perl module RNA.pm is required

Tags: perl

I am running a toolkit named RNA Framework that requires ViennaRNA to be installed.

I have installed the `ViennaRNA 2.4.14` to run a function named `rf-fold`, However, I constantly receive this error:

```
[!] Error: ViennaRNA package's Perl module RNA.pm is required.

Please ensure that `ViennaRNA package v2.2.0` (or greater) is installed and try again
```

When I check the missing RNA.pm module, I can see it is in this path:

```
/home/user/ViennaRNA/lib/site_perl/5.28.0/
```

when I check which Perl I am using (type: which Perl) it gives me:

```
/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/bin/perl
```

I tried different ways to install the ViennaRNA, including `conda install -c bioconda viennarna`, compile and make install from `ViennaRNA-2.4.14.tar.gz` file from the official website. But I cannot get over this error.

I saw a similar issue here and there is a solution (https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1052814), but I don't fully understand the content. Thanks in advance for any help and sorry if it is a basic question!

Comment: What does `perl -E "say for @INC"` give. Does it list the directory `/home/user/ViennaRNA/lib/site_perl/5.28.0` ?

Comment: It says:  /home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/site_perl/5.28.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/site_perl/5.28.0
/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/5.28.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.28.0/lib/5.28.0

Comment: Ok so it seems the module `RNA.pm` is not in `@INC` meaning you installed it with another `perl`. Try to install the module with the `perl` you used to print `@INC` above

Comment: May I ask how I should add "/home/user/ViennaRNA/lib/site_perl/5.28.0" to the list ?

Comment: you can run `perl` with `-I` option to alter the module search paths

Comment: something like: perl -MCPAN -e 'install RNA.pm' ?

Comment: Does the module exist on CPAN? I could not find it there

Comment: How did you get the module then?

Comment: So I should run something like: perl -I /home/user/Dropbox/biotools/ViennaRNA/lib/site_perl/5.28.0  ?

Comment: I have no idea..

Comment: I think the module come with the ViennaRNA-2.4.14.tar.gz file from the official website when I ./configure and sudo make install. I followed the procedure here:https://github.com/ViennaRNA/ViennaRNA

Comment: *"sudo make install"* : This is probably installing the module the wrong place. I guess this installs the module for the system perl, but if you are using the perlbrew perl later it will not work

Comment: I did `perlbrew off ` , then `which perl` ,it gives `/usr/bin/perl`. but it still gives the error `ViennaRNA package's Perl module RNA.pm is required.`

Answer (score 1):

I think the RNA.pm come with the package, when you download `ViennaRNA-2.4.14.tar.gz` and install following this [link](https://www.tbi.univie.ac.at/RNA/ViennaRNA/doc/html/install.html).

So I found my RNA.pm is in the directory:
`/share/apps/ViennaRNA-2.1.7/compile-install/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/RNA.pm`

And I modified the PERL5LIB environment variable by :
      `export PERL5LIB=/share/apps/ViennaRNA-2.1.7/compile-install/lib/`

Problem solved!

Comment: And this link is very helpful:https://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations

Comment: Great that you solved the problem. I downloaded the [ViennaRNA](https://github.com/ViennaRNA/ViennaRNA) repository, but I could not find any `RNA.pm` module in there, so I wonder where you got the file from

Comment: My directory to RNA.pm is `/share/apps/ViennaRNA-2.1.7/compile-install/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/`     In te other of my computer, the RNA.pm is in `/home/user/ViennaRNA/lib/site_perl/5.28.0/`. export both path works for me properly. Hope that helps!